# How to resize Favourites icons Safari New Tab

Tags: macos, safari, icon

### How to resize Favourites icons Safari New Tab

---

About a month ago, Safari received a new update, which brought significant changes to the new tab interface. As such, I've now noticed that the Favourites icons are now too small - for example, the names of some sites are going over onto two lines when they weren't before.

Is it possible to change the size of Favourites icons in the new Safari?